# Give first masonry/isotope random item a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-masonry, jquery-isotope

This is quite a complicated modification. I have a grid system set up using isotope. The client wants this grid to be random each time a user visits the page. This is easy to set up using isotope by adding sortBy: 'random'.

However, the first item in the isotope has a class of "featured". This featured class activates a wider grid element and some information for the user to click on so this will always be the first item in my grid.

Now, what I need to do is set the 1st element in the random sequence to be "featured" each time. So every time the user visits the page, the featured grid item will be different. At the moment, because I have hard coded the class featured, this just gets put randomly across the grid.

Is there anyway to give the first element in the random sequence a class? This is my code:

```
<script>
           var $container = $('#home-grid');

            $container.isotope({
              // options...
              resizable: true, // disable normal resizing
              sortBy : 'random',
              // set columnWidth to a percentage of container width
              masonry: { columnWidth: $container.width() / 2 }
            });

            $(window).smartresize(function(){
              $container.isotope({
                // update columnWidth to a percentage of container width
                masonry: { columnWidth: $container.width() / 2 }
              });
            });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to give the first isotope element in the random sequence a class!

Use the callback function and within that callback function, find out which element is positioned as the first element by looking for certain values of each Isotope element:

1. The matrix values of `transform` of each element: `tx` and `ty`
2. The `$container` padding values: `padding-top` and `padding-left`

Once you have those 4 values, check if the value of `tx` matches with `padding-left` and if the value of `ty` matches with `padding-top`.

If both conditions are true/matched, assign your custom class, eg. `.featured` to that element.

Comment: Thanks Shoda, However I think that's beyond me. Could u show me with code? Also D.Desandro wrote me back here ->https://github.com/desandro/isotope/issues/654#issuecomment-38434651